# How to write a long command within dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

I want to write the following command within Dockerfile using RUN instruction:

```
cat > /etc/myconfig.conf << EOL  
line 1, ${kernel}  
line 2,  
line 3, ${distro}  
line 4  
line 5   
EOL
```

I am doing it the following way but it seems wrong

```
RUN cat > /etc/myconfig.conf << EOL  \    
line 1, ${kernel}  \  
line 2,  \  
line 3, ${distro}  \  
line 4  \  
line 5   \  
EOL \
```

Comment: Why dont you put this in a script and run it?

Comment: can you please elaborate using an example?

Comment: You can put your commands in say "run.sh" and ADD, RUN

ADD run.sh /usr/local/bin/run.sh
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run.sh"]

Comment: Also look at Entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this directly from the Dockerfile (without an additional script), you can also `echo` it and escape the line breaks:

```
printf "line 1, ${kernel}\n line 2,\n line 3, ${distro}\n line 4\n line 5" >> /etc/myconfig.conf
```

But be careful: on windows systems you would need a `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

In the last line is without the slash
Example:

```
cat > "$VAR"/path/index.js << EOL \
code \
code \
EOL
```